# Checkbox checked depening on value binded via data-ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to edit a field and the checkbox should be checked or not checked depending on the existing data (1 for checked 0 for not checked)

```
<label class="icheck">{{property[key]}}
<input class="icheckbox_flat-blue" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="property[key]"  ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0 />
{{key | translate}}</label>
```

When i try realizing this with

```
ng-checked="property[key]==1"
```

the value isn't set to 0 when i click on the already checked checkbox and it takes 3 clicks to change the checkbox value.

Comment: A codepen would be useful, including some mocked up data in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="appCtrl.checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

this works for me with and without `ng-checked="appCtrl.checkbox==1"`, there is something in your code that is messing it up....

Comment: Well I think i found the problem. It seems that ng-true and ng-false only works with strings. So using strings solved it for me.

Comment: @Kbi i forgot to mention that this `ng-true-value=1` is not correct attr definistion, html attr values should always have double quotes around them.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with ng-true-value and ng-false-value when not using strings.

Using strings solved it for me.

```
<label class="icheck">{{property[key]}}
<input class="icheckbox_flat-blue" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="property[key]"  ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" />
{{key | translate}}</label>
```